# Posicionamento de imagens usando FlexBox

Tags: html5, css3

Sou iniciante em web e estou usando CSS grid na estrutura da minha página porém estou tentando posicionar uma imagem no centro da tela usando flexbox para tornar a pagina dinâmica mas não estou conseguindo.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="git">
         <img src="img/github.png" alt="github" class="image">
      </div>
      <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 100%;
   grid-template-rows: 100px;
   grid-gap: 10px;

}

.git img{
   display: flex;
   align-self: center;

}
```

Comment: "_porem estou tentando posicionar uma imagem na tela usando flexbox mas não to conseguindo_"... e? Se não disser o que não está conseguindo ou o que quer fazer fica difícil de ajudar.

Comment: opsss, acabei esquecendo da duvida, mds kkk, entao o q eu queria era posicionar a imagem no centro da tela usando flexbox, para tornar a pagina dinamica e talvez responsiva entende ? editei a pergunta.

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar ✔ na resposta que melhor atendeu nas suas perguntas. Olhando seu histórico de perguntas, nenhuma ainda foi finalizada. Isso é ruim para a comunidade porque o esforço dos usuários que dedicam tempo para ajudar outros usuários é recompensado quando a resposta é marcada como a melhor. Qualquer dúvida olhe a documentação [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para centralizar a imagem você deveria utilizar o flex na div onde está a imagem, e não na imagem em si, e usar a propriedade `justify-content: center;` para centralizar verticalmente dentro do grid:

```css
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 100%;
   grid-template-rows: 100px;
   grid-gap: 10px;
}

.git{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.git img{
   align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="git">
      <img src="img/github.png" alt="github" class="image">
   </div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```